# Reshape data from rows to column in dataframe in R

Tags: r, transform, reshape2

I want to reshape my data which is in the following form in dataframe :

```
a  b  Type_c d  e  
1  1   0     10 9
2  1   0     20 9 
3  2   1     30 4
4  2   2     40 3
5  3   3     50 2
6  3   0     60 1
7  4   3     70 2
8  4   2     80 7 
9  4   2     90 8
```

And would like to get the data in the following format by reshaping or transforming.

```
a  b  Type_0_d Type_0_e Type_1_d Type_1_e type_2_d type_2_e type_3_d  type_3_e  
1  1  10       9          0        0         0      0         0          0
2  1  20       9          0        0         0      0         0          0
3  2  0        0          30       4         0      0         0          0
4  2  0        0          0        0        40      3         0          0
5  3  0        0          0        0         0      0        50          2
6  3  60       1          0        0         0      0         0          0
7  4  0        0          0        0         0      0        70          2
8  4  0        0          0        0        80      7         0          0
9  4  0        0          0        0        90      8         0          0
```

I found it little difficult to do the same in R. However, in Tableau it was just straight forward. Just wanted to know if there's a way to do the same in R effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), a+b ~paste0("Type_", Type_c), value.var = c("d", "e"), fill = 0)
```

Comment: That is lovely. I ve been trying with `dcast` from `reshape` but I was nowhere close :/

Comment: @akrun : Thanks, this was great approach to work on. Simpler and faster.

Answer (score 2):

Another option maybe using `spread` of `tidyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% mutate(e1=Type_c) %>% spread(key = Type_c,value = d,fill = 0) %>% spread(key =e1,value = e,fill = 0)
```

I know this is a bad solution but still it is doing the job. Any suggestion regarding modification of the code is welcome. One more thing we have to rename the columns properly.

Comment: I would use `gather/spread` `gather(df1, Var, Val, d:e) %>% unite(Varc, Var, Type_c) %>% spread(Varc, Val, fill = 0)`